# DataPager value setting and getting with VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datapager

Is there some way to trap/get the value that a Data Pager advances to on the button click for Next or Previous record when navigating a ListView control?

And what about telling the pager which page to display programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the PagePropertiesChanging event to get current page

```
Protected Sub ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(sender As Object, e As PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs)
  Dim CurrentPage As Integer = (e.StartRowIndex / e.MaximumRows) + 1
  Response.Write(CurrentPage.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: Well this doesn't allow me to set the value the Data Pager is to point to. Its actually the navigation I would like to programmatically control on the data Pager. I am trying to animate the list view changing. Is there a better way?